# Add a separator to existing menu in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I added a package to sort lines, but the most used command `Sort` closely follows the existing command `Join Lines`. For usability, I'd like to put in a separator to split them. I don't own the sort lines package. I'm just asking to change on my local copy of Atom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, opened the code for the `sort-lines` package, went to `menus`, opened `sort-lines.cson`, and added `{ 'type': 'separator' }` under `submenu`.

Closed Atom and reopened, and the separator was there!